# Securing API using apigee

Tags: api, security, apigee

I have a server where my api is hosted -> `http://000.000.0.000:8080/todos`

I used apigee for managing my api security. -> http://inscripts-test.apigee.net/v1/api/todos?apikey=myapikeyhere

Those are the two URLs, one from my server and one that apigee generated for me using api key.

Ideally all api requests made to `http://000.000.0.000:8080` address should be rejected and calls should be allowed only to `http://inscripts-test.apigee.net` address.

I am new to the world of APIs, please help me understand how these security things should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:
You probably don't want to expose your apikey by posting it to StackOverflow. If you can, you'll want to go into the Developer Apps page and regenerate your key:
[image]

Locking down your backend requires changes at the backend, and may also require changes at the Apigee layer. To truly lock down your backend, you'll want to allow access only via https. Otherwise, your traffic and any security measures can be compromised between Apigee and your backend.

Given your change to use https, you have some options:

1. You can require authentication (username & password) and modify your backend to only allow authenticated users. Then assign the gateway a username and password and include them in communications.
2. Probably your most secure, and possibly easiest if you only allow https: you can use 2-way SSL (mutual authentication) between Apigee and your backend. Your backend validates that only the Apigee certificate is allowed to connect to your backend. See [this doc on setting up Apigee to target SSL](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/client-ssl-backend-servers).

Comment: Okay i guess second option is suitable for me. Thanks.